# Openfire serverside subscription to a node

Tags: xmpp, openfire

i am writing a plugin for openfire. in this plugin i want to create node and subscribe clients to this node. i am successful in creating the nodes but i am unable to subscribe client to it. i am using this code to subscibe client but no use.

Node retreived = pubsub.getNode(nodeId);
 NodeSubscription subscription = new NodeSubscription(retreived,
            new JID("dinga@exalanche"), new JID("dinga@exalanche"),
            State.subscribed, "sdfsdfdsds");
    retreived.addSubscription(subscription);
    retreived.approveSubscription(subscription, true);
    retreived.saveToDB();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

atlast i have found it.  it was simple

just one line

```
retreived.createSubscription(null, new JID("dinga@exalanche"), new JID("dinga@exalanche"), false, null);
```